# Unable to read a simple form field value with node.js and express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have started to learn Nodejs with express and web development. So for my first project I want to create a directory listing for which I have found a very nice HTML form. The code for the form is below:

```
<form action="/formSubmit" method="post" class="vanilla-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="column-100">
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Business Name" required="required">
        </div>

        <!-- Left column -->
        <div class="column-50">
            <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1" required="required">
            <input type="text" name="town" placeholder="Town" required="required">
            <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" required="required">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required="required">
        <label class="custom-select">
            <select name="Category">
                <option disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                <option>Academic Tuition</option>
                <option>Accountants</option>
                <option>Alterations</option>
                <option>Architectural Services</option>
            </select><span><!-- fake select handler --></span>
        </label>
        </div><!--
            Right column
        --><div class="column-50">
        <input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2">
        <input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Post Code" required="required">
        <input type="tel" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Phone" required="required">
        <input type="url" name="web" placeholder="Website" required="required">
        <input type="file" name="logo" placeholder="Your Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="column-100">
            <textarea name="description" placeholder="Business description" required="required"></textarea>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="true" required="required"><span><!-- fake checkbox --></span>
                <span >I agree to be contacted by RGSix.co.uk</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-100 center">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" data-error="Fix errors" data-processing="Sending..." data-success="Thank you!">
        </div>
        <footer class="notification-box"></footer>
    </form>
```

On the server side I want to just console log the data but I am unable to. My server side code is as follows:

```
app.post("/formSubmit", function(req, res){
  res.status(200);
  console.log("Busines Name is: "+req.body.Name);
});
```

The modules I am using are as follows:

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

The result of reading in my console is:
**Busines Name: undefined**

I need help in understanding where I am going wrong please.

**EDIT**
Screenshot of my console after submitting the form

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this in my [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/ScarcePaltryTitles#index.js) using the code you provided.

Comment: If I just try to print **req** and not the whole body.Name, I get -> Busines Name is: [object Object]

Comment: What appears in your console if you use `console.dir(req.body)`?

Comment: @esqew I get { }

Comment: Can you also *please* check to ensure the code you’ve provided here closely resembles/matches what you’re running in the screenshot output you provided? I slightly suspect there may be something else in your code that materially differs from what you’ve provided in the question that could potentially be causing the behavior you’ve described because I wasn’t able to recreate it in the Repl linked above - this is also informed by the fact that the string you’ve prepended to your console logging doesn’t match between the screenshot (`Business Name is:‘) and the code you posted (`Busines Name:`).

Comment: I tried with just creating a simple form and the server part seems to work. It seems something is up with the html form, it is sending the data in some weird object form, at least this is what my understanding is going towards

Comment: @esqew sorry but I just changed the string, nothing else - code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my body - I had this culprit -

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            var myForm;
            myForm = new VanillaForm(document.querySelector("form.vanilla-form"));
        });
    </script>
```

When I commented it, it started working fine. Can anyone please tell me what does it do as I have not studied it yet and will removing it cause problems down the line?

Comment: If you want to ask a question off the back of this I would recommend editing this into the body of your question and re-work it so that it's asking about this specifically (why the invocation of `VanillaForm()` would cause this) - Stack Overflow guidelines don't allow for asking of follow-up questions within the Answers section (as they aren't strictly that - Answers). (This also goes back to my point about ensuring ALL of your code was included, as this was not part of the HTML you provided initially)

Comment: When you edit your question to include this information, please also elaborate on where the `VanillaForm` package is from (with a link) and *why* exactly you need it. Both aren't clear from this snippet, and I can't find very much information about the `VanillaForm` package itself on Google.

Answer (score -1):

Earlier you were sending response first and then executing the console log. Please try this will solve your problem.

```
app.post("/formSubmit", function(req, res){
  console.log("Busines Name: "+req.body.Name);
  res.status(200);
});
```

Comment: Nops, didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Did you research this prior to answering? There is absolutely no factual basis in the implication that you cannot continue processing data from `req` after sending a response back to the client. [Relevant link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3275-you-can-continue-to-process-an-express-js-request-after-the-client-response-has-been-sent.htm) (among many other articles and documentation pages).

Comment: @esqew Thank's for correcting me appreciated. Did you find the solution?